# Why do Spring offer its own task executors?

Tags: java, spring, threadpool, executorservice

Why do we need `AsyncTaskExecutor` (and it's implementations, i.e. `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`), when Java offers those already (through `Executors`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TaskExecutor`is basically a Spring abstraction over the standard JDK's `Executor`.

> Equivalent to JDK 1.5's `java.util.concurrent.Executor` interface; extending it now in Spring 3.0, **so that clients may declare a dependency on an `Executor` and receive any `TaskExecutor` implementation.**
>
> <sup>[The Javadoc of `org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html)</sup>

Spring guys build own ecosystem and care how it can coexist with the standard JDK means. Usually, these implementations are more competitive, API-richer and Spring-orientated (actively used within the Spring Framework itself).

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is an implementation of `AsyncTaskExecutor`, which is by default used when running `@Async` methods. You can however provide your own `TaskExecutor` to be used instead of the default one. The reason why Spring does it is to give you more flexibility.